# OpenSSL: what's the difference between -kfile and -pass?

Tags: encryption, passwords, cryptography, openssl, aes

It seems both `-kfile` and `-pass` can be used to encrypt files with a 2048 bit keyfile? I don't understand the difference between the two methods:

```
$ openssl enc -salt -aes-256-cbc -in inputfile.txt -kfile 2048bit_keyfile.key 

$ openssl enc -salt -aes-256-cbc -in inputfile.txt -pass file:2048bit_keyfile.key -out outputfile.txt.enc
```

Which method uses the full entropy of the 2048 bit keyhole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## -k and -kfile are deprecated

The OpenSSL [ENC wiki page](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Enc#Options) says this:

> **-k *password*, -kfile *filename***
> Both option [sic] are used to specify a password or a file containing the password which is used for key derivation. However **they are deprecated.** You should use the *-pass* option instead. The equivalents are **-pass pass:***password* and **-pass file:***filename* respectively.